# Hyperlink in yahoomail not clickable, using .NET C#

Tags: c#, email, yahoo

So, the idea is to send an email from .NET C# code and that is being done by using an Email Model. The email object will compose an email, provided your yahoo mail is logged in your browser and the email body has a hyperlink which should be clickable. I tried everything from launching an anchor tag to writing a complete html. Please see this

```
emailModel.ToEmailAddress = emailModel.ToEmailAddress.Replace(',', ';');                
emailModel.IsHtml = true;
string emailLInk1 = "<html><body><h1>My Message</h1><br><a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com/\n'>http://www.stackoverflow.com/\n</a></body></html>";     
emailModel.EmailBody =(isEmailNeedsFormat)? string.Format("{0} ^~^~ {1} ^~^~ {2} ^~^~ {3} ^~^~ {4}", emailBody, clickText,emailLInk1, newSignature, emailModel.EmailFooter):emailBody;
```

I tried using `'\n'` after the link for this yahoo mail. Apparently nothing works. Interesting enough, yahoo help says we need to insert the email link like this - https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN3385.html

I don't know how to get this done through how I want.

Comment: The link is completely irrelevant, it is for some share button. Remove that '\n' from link, probably will help. But just use "Inspect element" in actual email to see whats up.

Comment: You can't just stick <html> tags into the middle of an email like that. You need to read a basic html primer. Your problem has nothing to do with C# or yahoo

Comment: Try to use `@` at the beginning of emaillink variable `string emailLInk1 = @"<html><body><h1>My Message</h1><br><a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com/'>http://www.stackoverflow.com/</a></body></html>";`

Comment: I tried with just the anchor tag before; this was like the attempt when it really pushed me up to a point, when i was really trying everything. I tried removing the html tags, the '\n', nothing changed and tried putting the @ in the beginning too.

About what it shows in the inspect of the yahoo mail - it shows the entire thing as a paragraph with <p> element.